# Getting a negative sum in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {793810624, 895642170, 685903712, 623789054, 468592370};
    miniMaxSum(arr);
}

static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    long min = 0;
    long max = 0;
    long minSum = 0, maxSum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        min += arr[j];
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
        max += arr[j];
    }

    minSum = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    maxSum = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4];

    System.out.print(minSum);
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(maxSum);
}
```

Hey everybody, got a question. I got two separate ways to calculate the min and max Sums. When this example is run however, I get negative values for the minSum/maxSum while the for loops give me the answer I am expecting.

Why is the summations giving a negative? Some sort of integer overflow? The minSum IntelliJ is returning is -1722871536 and maxSum is -1295821736.

Comment: Maximum size of an `int` in Java is 2^31-1 which is `2147483647`. I suspect you're overflowing that number with all of your additions, which puts the representation into negative `int` land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Integer math. When adding integers the result is an integer. Even when it overflows (as you *guessed*), and then you ***widen*** it to a `long`. Widen one term before performing addition to fix.

```
minSum = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + (long) arr[3];
maxSum = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + (long) arr[4];
```

And, to validate,

```
System.out.print(minSum == min);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(maxSum == max);
```

Outputs

```
true true
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered it for me. Changing the initial array type to long[] instead of int[] also fixed it!

Comment: And on a quasi-related note, this is why `comparators` should not do `return a-b` for their comparison results but should return explicit `-1, 1, or 0` as required.